# If statement selecting only first value in linq2xml query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that's being read. I'm trying to check if Product.Id is in the XML file. The problem: it only reads the first XML Product values.

I have the following if-statement:

```
    if ((int)user.ElementAt(0).Element("Product").Element("Id") == product.Id)
    {
       // Do some logic
    }
```

User select looks like this:

```
    var user = from item in doc.Descendants("User")
               where (string)item.Element("Username") == username
               select item.Element("UserProducts");
```

The select results in this XML:

```
<UserProducts>
  <Product>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Mouse</Name>
    <Amount>2</Amount>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Keyboard</Name>
    <Amount>1</Amount>
  </Product>
</UserProducts>
```

The if statement only checks the first Product entry (ID 1, Name Mouse, Amount 2). It does not check the second entry.

Why does it not check the second entry, and how can I fix it so it checks all entries?

Expected output:
An if statement that checks all product entries, and not only the first entry.

Comment: the linq names have to match xml.  Change From : User to : Product.  Then Change From : Username To : Name  And finally select item

Comment: @jdweng i think the Xml posted in the question is the result of `user` query not the original xml

Answer (score 0):

Add `.ToList()` after `select item.Element("UserProducts")` and check if condition in `foreach` loop

Comment: I get a "'XElement' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'" error in my IDE.

Comment: have you used `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is that I'm not creating a new object, (with a select new Object statement), so it can't ToList a query?